# best way of implementing large 2D bit array

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, bit

i'm teaching myself some more advanced Java by optimising a Game of Life program.

So far i've sped it up using multithreading and marking portions of the world Dirty.
However, the World array is currently a 2D array of bytes and creating a world size much larger than 30000*30000 causes a java heap space error.
what better ways are there of storing a very large 2D array of booleans/bits?

Comment: Look at how an ImageRaster works: it uses `long[]`, which is a 'well packed type'. The operations decompose the 2d-to-1d lookup and work on component (R/G/B) values as bits. Using this approach a 30k x 30k field would only take up ~112MB.

Answer (score 3):

You could use one large `BitSet` with 30,000 x 30,000 bits.

But even then memory consumption will be rather high and you might get severe performance issues. Possibly a more clever solution using a sparse data structure that holds only non-empty portions of the entire world might be necessary.

See also [SparseBitSet](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/SparseBitSet).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the 'Hashlife' algorithm. That implements your 2D bit array as a 'quad tree'. Non-leaf nodes point to 4 sub-nodes (North West, North East, South West, South East) that have half the span of the parent node. That builds up a 2D bit array and has a very clever 'memoized' algorithm for calculating future generations.

Here is a walk through that fortunately for you is demonstrated in Java:

http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/an-algorithm-for-compressing-space-and-t/184406478